# JavaScript Audio : MEDIA12899 AUDIO/VIDEO : type MIME

Tags: javascript, audio, internet-explorer-11

I'm playing an audio file with this code :

```
var snd = new Audio("sound.wav"); // buffers automatically when created
snd.play();
```

This was working well on every up-to-date well known browsers when I deployed my website (mid-2013).

However, today I've re-tested this functionality on IE11 and the sound hasn't been played.
Opening the standard developper console on IE11 gives me this error :

> MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDÉO : type MIME.

And it still works on Firefox 27.0.1

Thank you for your help.

---

**EDIT 07/10/2014 :**

Command:

```
$ file sound.wav
```

Outputs:

```
sound.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 44100 Hz
```

Command:

```
$ curl -I http://localhost/sound.wav
```

Outputs:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 10 Jul 2014 13:15:48 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Mon, 17 Mar 2014 14:38:26 GMT
ETag: "2de0e7e-52a5c-4f4ce5f4a7c80"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 338524
Content-Type: audio/wav
```

Comment: same error happens in IE11 with HTML5 video. Been working on it but still have not found a fix. I am leaning towards scripting in a process to handle and alternative way to play when IE11 is detected. But that's not a great solution.

Comment: IE11 does not support audio/wav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found that IE does not support wav format in audio or video HTML elements.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Found similar question answered in another post:

- [Using html audio with IE: MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301748/using-html-audio-with-ie-media12899-audio-video-unknown-mime-type)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `AddType audio/wav .wav` to your .htaccess file to make sure it knows how to encode the file?

Comment: I had `Content-Type: audio/x-wav`, now it's `Content-Type: audio/wav`but still not working.