# Using html audio with IE: MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type

Tags: html, internet-explorer, audio, mime

Html is following:

```
<audio id="audioCap" preload="auto" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

Js:

```
$('#audioCap')[0].play();
```

And setting "src" as follows:

```
$('#audioCap').attr('src', 'http://blabla/captcha/captcha.wav?' + response);
```

Where `response` is an id.

This works well with all browsers except IE versions (9-11) which should also work. I'm getting `MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type`. I did some research and found out that it should be a server configuration problem. I captured the network data with the debug tools and checked the response headers. `Content-Type` is shown as `audio/wav` which is true. I don't know what else could cause this error.

Comment: IE doesn't support wav-files. You will need to provide the audio in a different format for IE

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Unfortunately, its because Internet Explorer doesn't support `wav`-Files.**

In order to get cross-browser compatibility, you'll need to provide the same audio-file in several different formats.

Take a look at the table on this site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

In order to support IE, you need to add an `mp3` or `mp4`-format.

To provide the correct format for the current Browser, you can use something like this:

```
var source= document.createElement('source');
if (audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;')) {
    source.type= 'audio/mpeg';
    source.src= 'audio/song.mp3';
} else {
    source.type= 'audio/wav';
    source.src= 'audio/song.wav';
}
audio.appendChild(source);
```

*(Source: [How can I add multiple sources to an HTML5 audio tag, programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053262/how-can-i-add-multiple-sources-to-an-html5-audio-tag-programmatically))*

**Edit:** It's worth to note, that you have the same problems with audio, video and fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I read different stuff at alot of forums. I'll set up the server to serve both mp3 and wav.